# How can I prove this inequality involving logarithm?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> $n^2 \geq n \log_{2}n$

I tried like this:

$n^2 \geq n \log_{2}n$

$n^2-n \log_{2}n \geq 0$

$n(n-\log_2 n) \geq 0$

I don't know what to do after this?

Comment: you should fix the latex syntax cause I'm not sure I get your expressions

Comment: First divide by $n$...

Comment: @LeeMosher: I think you will lose one root '0' by dividing by n

Comment: $0$ cannot be a root. It is not in the domain of $\log_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**: that means $2^n \geq n$ and it can be done with easy induction